# There is data type error in code where the type is boolean instead of integer

Tags: c#, arrays

So in C# I was writing a simple code:-

*To check if a coordinate is inside the circle or not*

But as soon as I compiled the program below

```
public static void Main() 
        {
            int[] centre={0,0};
            int r=5;
            Console.Write("Coordinates: ");
            int pointX=Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            int pointY=Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            bool checkFirst=((pointX - centre[0])^2)+((pointY - centre[1])^2)== r^2;
            string check= checkFirst ? "true" : "false";
            Console.WriteLine(
                "It is {0} that {1},{2} is inside circle {3} of radius {4}.",
                check,pointX,pointY,centre,r);
            
        }
```

On the line of *pointX - centre* the error thats shown is that **the subtraction is in bool and I can't square it**

If I removed the centre and wrote any integer the answer is correct.

Plz help!!!

Comment: `^` is not the "power" operator (which doesn't exist), but a bitwise XOR

Comment: FYI an `int` is an `Int32`, so the correct parse would be Convert.ToInt32 - but this is not the source of your problem. Int16 == short

Comment: Heads up: the "ToString" of "centre" is "System.Int32[]", not "(0,0)" - you will need to specify the values individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Math.Pow` method to calculate the powers:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] centre = { 0, 0 };
    int r = 5;
    Console.Write("Coordinates: ");
    int pointX = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    int pointY = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    bool checkFirst = Math.Pow(pointX - centre[0], 2) + Math.Pow(pointY - centre[1], 2) <= Math.Pow(r, 2);
    string check = checkFirst ? "true" : "false";
    Console.WriteLine($"It is {check} that {pointX},{pointY} is inside circle {centre} of radius {r}.");
}
```

Comment: Urrgh. `Math.Pow` is so much more expensive than `(pointX - centre[0])*(pointX - centre[0])`.

Comment: @Enigmativity But how much more readable :)